# Pocket-size Talmud/Gemara

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, jewish-books, size

Is there is a pocket-size Gemara? Soft cover preferred. This would be a great invention if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: I saw a new set in a bookstore in 5 Towns about 2.5 months ago. I almost bought it. Kinda wish I had.

Comment: I'm also wondering...the Gemara is by far the most studied Sefer by Jews, and they don't even have one officially?

Comment: If you have a mobile device, you can get a PDF of any Masechta from hebrewbooks.org. Plus there's an artscroll app for iOS on the way.

Comment: @YaakovKuperman – How do you get PDF of an entire Masechta from the site? I can only figure out how to download a single amud at a time.

Answer (score 14):

- Artscroll is currently making travel-sized paperback [English Gemaras](http://www.eichlers.com/Product/Artscroll_Books/Talmud/Artscroll-Schottenstein-Edition-of-the-Talmud---Paperback-Travel-Edition-_405-5.html). Each only has about 1 or 2 chapters.
  Size:  7" x 10"
- There's also a ["personal-sized" paperback Oz Vehadar](http://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/oz-vehadar-edition-personal-size-shas-set---20-volumes-paperback-S915116.html).
  Size: 6.5 X 9.5
- [Blum Edition](http://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/blum-edition-small-size-shas---20-volumes-S130366.html)  hardcover travel Gemara.
  Size:   5.25" X 8.25"

---

Historically, after WWII the Vaad Hatzalah [printed pocket sized Gemaras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivors'_Talmud) for survivors in the refugee camps.

Comment: +1 for the historical reference (and the rest of the answer as well)!

Comment: I think the Oz Vehadar is the one I saw in the 5 Towns. Looks nice.

Comment: The link is broken for the Blum Edition.

Comment: @Adam Mosheh I changed the link to the same set but in hardcover instead of paperback.

Answer (score 1):

Use E-Daf or some similar website or application on your smartphone!!!

Comment: (@Vram) I go according to my own reasoning - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/

Comment: Shouldn't it be spelled מצוה הבאה בעבירה?

Comment: Download the PowerSefer Daf Yomi app for your smartphone or tablet, for free!

Answer (score 0):

I have been printing my own for a while now: it's very cheap, ridiculously easy and extremely convenient.

Go to HebrewBooks.org and click the tab marked "Mishna/Shas" ([link](http://hebrewbooks.org/mishnashas)). Download the PDF that you want, and then edit it as you see fit. (Myself, I always delete all the material from the back, since I only want the gemara itself and it's best for it not to be too bulky. Note that if you delete material from the front, you want to make sure that you're deleting an even number of pages, or the pagination will be different to a usual printed masekhta.)

Go to the website of your local copy centre. I live in Australia, and use [OfficeWorks](https://www.officeworks.com.au/).

Send them a PDF, but make sure that you send it to them upside down so that they put the binding on the right side of the page and not the left. Choose the binding that you prefer (I like the solid metal ring binding, personally), back and front covers (I go for the black cardboard at the back and the frosted plastic cover on the front), the paper size and paper quality, and away you go.

In my experience, working with OfficeWorks in Sydney, it has never taken more than two days for me to collect my masekhta, it is exactly as I ordered it, and generally under $20. It's easy for reading on the bus or the train, and when you're done with it you can just dump it at your local chevra.

Comment: Aren't those pdfs copyrighted?

Comment: Of course they're not - nothing on HebrewBooks.org is copyright. Everything there is for downloading. Whether or not I would be able to sell it is a different question.