# When the Cohen is asked to leave the shul, doesn't that force him to miss the mitzvah of hearing part of Kri'at Hatorah?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, torah-reading

Occasionally, when there is a weekday simcha in my shul and the gabbai wants to give aliyot to 3 Yisra'elim, he asks the Cohen to leave the shul, which he does.

So, by requesting him to do this, isn't he preventing him from the mitzvah of listening to the public Torah reading? Does he really need to leave the shul?

Comment: is that mitzvah on the individual or on the tzibbur?

Comment: He can reappear once the Yisroel has finished his brocho. I've done it.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman - Hmmm ... I need to explore that one.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Finish? Why not start?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, I was once at a shiur at Orach Chaim in New York and the conclusion that was reached was that the mitzvah is on the tzibbur.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, Rav Moshe Feinstein doesn't hold that way (just to bring the other opinion).

Comment: @Yishai Source?

Comment: @doubleaa http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/must-one-go-according-to-his-her-opinion-leshitato/33325#comment84634_33325

Answer (score 2):

The practice among the Kohanim that I know is to leave from before the Yisroel is called up until after he starts Baruchu. Then they come back. If they come back before that, they may need to get the Aliyah and the Yisroel held that Bimah until the third Aliyah.

Source - observed practice (I was the Yisroel in that situation many years ago - and that is what the Rabbi paskened).